# File from resource Uri in JNI

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, uri

Hi I'm trying to get a File object from the Uri of a drawable resource. I'm using this code:

```
jclass clazz;
jmethodID methodID;
jstring string1, string2, string3;
jobject object1, object2;

clazz = env->FindClass("android/net/Uri");
methodID = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "parse", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/net/Uri;");
string1 = env->NewStringUTF("android.resource://com.appsite.android/drawable/grass");
object1 = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(clazz, methodID, string1);
methodID = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
string1 = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(object1, methodID);

clazz = env->FindClass("java/net/URLEncoder");
methodID = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "encode", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");
string2 = (jstring)env->NewStringUTF("UTF-8");
string3 = (jstring)env->CallStaticObjectMethod(clazz, methodID, string1, string2);


clazz = env->FindClass("java/net/URI");
methodID = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
object1 = env->NewObject(clazz, methodID, string3);

clazz = env->FindClass("java/io/File");
methodID = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "<init>", "(Ljava/net/URI;)V");
object2 = env->NewObject(clazz, methodID, object1);
```

The application crashes at the last call to `NewObject`. What are the possible reasons for that?

**EDIT**:

It seems like a problem with passing a `jobject` as parameter to `NewObject` like that. What is the proper way to pass a `jobject` to `NewObject`?

Comment: Step 1 would be to add error checking for every JNI call (i.e. check return values and exceptions).

Comment: I actually use error checking in my code, I only omitted that to make the post shorter.

Comment: There's nothing special about passing a `jobject`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to JNI.

The problem is that there no **java.io.File** for the drawable resource. The *grass* drawable is embedded in the APK in PNG or other image format, and the resource manager extracts the bitmap for `Resources.getDrawable(int)` by looking into the APK directly.

If you need to access your bitmap with file i/o methods, the closest you can get is thorough [Resources.openRawResourceFd()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResourceFd(int)) method (limited to uncompressed resources). You can also put the bitmap in **assets** instead of **res**.